# JavaScript and Json issue

Tags: javascript, json, discord

**[Update]
I Have chosen to go with the database now and make a new collection for each command, it will then collect all the users that use the command.**

Does anyone know how I can get multiple arrays in my Json file, I have 3 slash commands on discord that I a trying to collect data from, However when I use to command it just updates the current array in the Json file, I would like to either get all the uses of each command. So that then I can import the Json files to Mongodb.

I am new to JavaScript and using Mongodb so I am still learning so I would really appreciate all the help I can get below I will provide my code samples so you can see if I am doing something wrong.

**Example of what I want to achieve**

```js
{
  "id": "281185483717869569",
  "command": "architect",
  "name": "UKzs",
  "description": [
    {
      "value": "569",
      "name": "x"
    },
    {
      "value": "663",
      "name": "y"
    },
{ 
  "id": "281185483717869569",
  "command": "duke",
  "name": "UKzs",
  "description": [
    {
      "value": "123",
      "name": "x"
    },
    {
      "value": "123",
      "name": "y"
    }
  ]
}
  ]
}
```

**JavaScipt File**

```js
Client.ws.on("INTERACTION_CREATE", async (interaction, msg) => {
  const command = interaction.data.name.toLowerCase();
  const args = interaction.data.options;

  console.log(args);

  const title = {
    id: interaction.member.user.id,
    command: command,
    name: interaction.member.user.username,
    description: args,
  };

  fs.writeFile("title.json", JSON.stringify(title, null, 2), (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("File has been written");
    }
  });

  if (command == "duke") {
    const description = args.map((opt) => {
      return opt.value;
    });
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Would like the duke title!`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`These are my Coordinates \n ${description}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setAuthor(interaction.member.user.username);

    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
      data: {
        type: 4,
        data: await createAPIMessage(interaction, embed),
      },
    });
  }
  if (command == "architect") {
    const description = args.map((opt) => {
      return opt.value;
    });
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Would like the architect title!`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`These are my Coordinates \n ${description}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setAuthor(interaction.member.user.username);

    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
      data: {
        type: 4,
        data: await createAPIMessage(interaction, embed),
      },
    });
  }
  if (command == "scientist") {
    const description = args.map((opt) => {
      return opt.value;
    });
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Would like the scientist title!`)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`These are my Coordinates \n ${description}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setAuthor(interaction.member.user.username);

    Client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
      data: {
        type: 4,
        data: await createAPIMessage(interaction, embed),
      },
    });
  }
});
```

**Json File**

```js
[
  {
    "id": "281185483717869569",
    "command": "architect",
    "name": "UKzs",
    "description": [
      {
        "value": "123",
        "name": "x"
      },
      {
        "value": "123",
        "name": "y"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

As you can see there is only one input there from the command, If I use another command like /duke then input my data on discord then it will just update the above Json file.

Even better if someone can point me in the right direction on how to get this to save to a database then I would appreciate it, I am not 100% sure on how to do but I think it has something to do with schemas.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for answering with a question.  But does "...how I can get multiple arrays in my Json file..." mean "how can I nest arrays in JSON?"  Is what you want to know is how to define a JSON array within another JSON array?

If that's what sought, it's:

```
[
  {
    "id": "281185483717869569",
    "command": "architect",
    "name": "UKzs",
    "array-within-array": [1,2,3, ["one", "two", "three"]],
    "description": [
      {
        "value": "123",
        "name": "x"
      },
      {
        "value": "123",
        "name": "y"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the reply. I am struggling to explain it because I don't know that much. So my 3 commands on discord are: /duke | /architect | /scientist as you can see from my Json file it has stored the command "architect" however if I then use /duke or /scientist then it will just update the file from architect to duke or scientist. I want to try to get all the data everytime the command is used.

Comment: So instead of getting arrays I should have said strings